# How to show location markers on openstreet map from csv file in PHP

Tags: php, csv, geolocation, openstreetmap

Can anyone help me on how to show location markers on openstreet map from csv file in PHP? The CSV file contains records of coordinates (lat,long) and name of a place corresponding to each coordinate. I would like to integrate the location map in a website

Comment: simply use php to read the data from the csv, then generate the necessary js code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the Leaflet Javascript library to display your map:

You can either read the CSV using PHPs `fgetcsv()` function line by line and add Leaflet markers one by one generating

L.marker([lat_val, lon_val]).addTo(map);

lines to add your locations.

When also wanting to display names you may want to check the Leaflet PopUp and ToolTip methods. See https://leafletjs.com/reference.html

Or if your CSV file is available via HTTP you can use e.g. the Leaflet "Omnivore" plugin to load and process the CSV data on the Javascript side in the browser directly:

https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore